# strong convexity definition

Tags: convex-analysis

For strongly convex functions, it is stated that 
    for some $\mu>0$,

1. $$f(y)\geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y−x)+\frac{\mu}{2}\|y−x\|^2, \quad \forall x,y.$$
2. $$(\nabla f(x)−\nabla f(y))^T(x−y)≥\mu\|x−y\|^2, \quad \forall x,y.$$

How does one prove that 2) implies 1)?

Comment: I've converted your post to MathJax but there were some areas where I had to guess at what you meant. In particular I'm not certain if the $\mu$s should all be squared or not. Please review and check that's what there is correct.  (And also, please use MathJax when posting.  There are guides on the site.)

Comment: it has to be $\mu/2$ instead of $\mu^2$

Comment: @daw thanks!  Fixed that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Taylor expansion: Take $x,y$. Then 
$$\begin{split}
f(y)& = f(x) + \int_0^1\nabla f(x + s(y-x))^T(y-x)\ ds \\
&= f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+ \int_0^1(\nabla f(x + s(y-x))-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x)\ ds\\
&\ge  f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+ \int_0^1\mu s\|x-y\|^2\ ds\\
&=  f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+ \frac\mu2 \|x-y\|^2.
\end{split}$$

Comment: Thanks. could you explain the first step? I looked at the Taylor's expansion for partials (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_integral_form_of_the_remainder). Before the integral, there are 2 summations. What happened to these summations?

Comment: The first step is just the fundamental theorem applied to the function $t\mapsto f(x+t(y-x))$